# invalid_request could not parse claims parameter

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am having a problem making a request to the Banno Plugin I do not have this issue when the "View More" section is clicked. I belive that I have found the issue but looks like I cannot reach out to banno directly so wanted to see if there is anyone that has seen this issue.

When reaching out to the auth "a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth" endpoint I have assigned claims to the payload

```
{"userinfo":{"address":null,"birthdate":null}}
```

But when reviewing the error request I get a invalid_request could not parse claims parameter request on the claim but the claim is no longer the claim I gave it and is injecting **/a/consumer/api** to the first json object  like below:

```
{"userinfo":{"address":/a/consumer/api,"birthdate":null}}
```

When I use the Card Action to this external application it works as expected but while in the plugin card it fails due to the parsed claim.

Any feedback would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are you URL encoding the characters claims payload?

The example you've given:

`{"userinfo":{"address":null,"birthdate":null}}`

...would look like this once it is encoded:

`%7B%22userinfo%22%3A%7B%22address%22%3Anull%2C%22birthdate%22%3Anull%7D%7D`

Comment: Hey Jaime, I was URL encoding but I was able to resolve this issue I hade the redirect in the redirectUri and looks like that causes an issue somehow I moved make the auth call on my application and it no longer injects the "/a/consumer/api" in the claim

Comment: Do you have an example of the problem which could be shared in a (redacted) curl command (or similar)? I'm glad that it sounds like you've worked around the problem, but I don't think I fully understand the precise problem itself.